# Component get's called without button click

Tags: html, reactjs, components

I want to make a program about pokemons using pokeApi which has a navbar with 2 buttons: PokemonList and TypeList.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/Navbar";
import PokemonList from "./components/PokemonList";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pokemons: undefined,
  };

  getPokemons = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_call = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon");
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log("Data logging should come here!");
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
      pokemons: data.results,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar getPokemons={this.getPokemons} />
        <PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my NavBar.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  NavbarText,
  NavDropdown,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  Button,
} from "react-bootstrap";

const NavBar = (props) => (
  <Navbar bg="bg" expand="lg">
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link onClick={props.getPokemons}>Pokemons</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#link">Types</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);

export default NavBar;
```

and here is my PokemonList.js

```
import React from "react";

class PokemonList extends React.Component {
  getKeys = function () {
    console.log(this.props);
    return Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
  };

  getHeader = function () {
    let keys = this.getKeys();
    return keys.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={key}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  getRowsData = function () {};

  render() {
    const RenderRow = (props) => {
      let items = this.props.data;
      let keys = this.getKeys();
      return items.map((row, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <RenderRow key={index} data={row} keys={keys} />
          </tr>
        );
      });
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.getRowsData()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PokemonList;
```

My problem is that I start the app with npm start and I get an error:

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
In the PokemonList.js -> getKeys() function.

I don't get it, because the fetch should only be called if I click the PokemonList button, but it gets called at start. Any idea? And the other one is that my NavBar.js is ugly because of the imports are there any other way to import those things in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the pokemons data with an asynchronous function, so what happens is the component gets rendered when the pokemons data still need to be returned.

In order to fix it, try wrapping your PokemonList component with a condition; This way we display the PokemonList component only when the pokemons data get retrieved:

```
{this.state.pokemons && <PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} />}
```

To notice I used the '&&' operator, which is a shortcut for if statements - in javascript, it evaluates the first expression and if that returns 0 or "" or false or undefined or null, then it doesn't evaluate the expression after the '&&' operator.

Alternative of that sintax, is this way:

```
{this.state.pokemons ? <PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} /> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont passed any props to your `<PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} />` Componnet.

you should do somthing like this in your App.js:

```
import PokemonList from "./components/PokemonList";
...
...
<PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} data={this.state.data} />
...
...
```